# Getting the clicked element using $(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery

hey I have this silly issue and I hope you could help me to solve it. I have some "a" elements and I just want to add an active class when clicked.

I tried this :

```
<a href="javascript:mifunction()"></a>

js:
function mifunction(){
 $(this).addClass('active');
}
```

but it doesn't work, so I tried this:

```
<a></a>

js:
$('a').click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('active');               
});
```

It doesn't work either. It just worked when I mixed both. But users have to dubbleclick the element, which is not an option:

```
<a href="javascript:mifunction()"></a>
js:

function mifunction(){
 $('a').click(function() {
   $(this).addClass('active');              
 });
}
```

Do you have any idea of how to solve this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Your second code example should do it. Maybe you have made something wrong in your program?

Comment: Surely there is something wrong, It so strange, what do you think it could be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is working here with your 2nd example:

- ### Demo

May be you need to wrap your jQuery code in :

```
$(function() {

  $('a').click(function() {
     $('a.active').removeClass('active'); // you may also want to remove previous
     $(this).addClass('active');               
  });

});
```

Also make sure that you included jQuery library path in your HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/jQuery.min.js"></script>
```

**OR:**

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

### EDIT:

*(Links are added dynamically)*

```
$(function() {

  $('a').on( 'click', function() {
     $('a.active').removeClass('active'); // you may also want to remove previous
     $(this).addClass('active');               
  });

});
```

Comment: No, I did all those things and it doesn't work. I am creating those "a" elements dinamically, do you think is that the problem?

Comment: Yes. it can be a problem. Try: `$('a').on('click', function() { /** your code **/ });`

Comment: yay! It worked, Thanks! Could you explain me why that happen? would you post it as an answer please? just in case someone have the same problem.

Comment: Normally jQuery is implemented on existing HTML. You need to tell specially that it will be implemented on future HTML as well. Editing my answer with your new requirements.

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing and matching old and new ways of working with the DOM and JavaScript.

The

```
$('a').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('active');
}
```

Should work fine.

Just put that inside a `$(document).ready(function() {});`

So.. literally it should look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('a').click(function() { 
            $(this).addClass('active');
        });
    });
</script>
<a>Click me</a>
```

---

Also, if you're just trying to style.. you can do it via CSS
For Active:  `a:active { color: orange; }`
For Visited: `a:visited { color:green; }`

Comment: I already did that but it doesn't work, I don't understand what could be :(

Answer (score 2):

Your problem must exist somewhere else, because this works fine:

```
$('a').click(function () {
   $(this).addClass('active'); 
});​
```

If you are creating the anchors dynamically, you should use `.on()` instead:

```
$('#container').on('click', 'a', function () {
    $(this).addClass('active'); 
});
```

Example with `.on()`: http://jsfiddle.net/jbabey/bqgFN/1/

Documentation for `.on()`: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 1):

Try doing it like below,

```
<a class="link" href="javascript:void(0)"></a>

$(function () {
   $('.link').click (function () {
      $(this).addClass('active');
   });
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work and it says that ther's a syntax error in the void() part

Comment: @lilymz my bad.. it should have been `:void(0)`